# Adding a new Class file and doesn't touch anything else more

Tags: android, class, imageview

I tried a tutorial: Learn Java Like a Kid Build Fun Desktop and Mobile Apps
And I have problems with Android Studio.
Indeed what I have done is only create a class BubbleView:
But I don't know what I have to do with the xml files...
thanks

I've tried to modify some main_activity but it doesn't work!

```
import...

public class  BubbleView extends ImageView implements    View.OnTouchListener {
private ArrayList<Bubble> bubbleList;
private final int DELAY = 16;
private Paint myPaint = new Paint();
private Handler h;

public BubbleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    bubbleList = new ArrayList<Bubble>();
    myPaint.setColor(BLACK);
    h = new Handler();
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

private class Bubble {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int size;
    public int color;
    public int xspeed;
    public int yspeed;
    private final int MAX_SPEED = 5;

    public Bubble(int newX, int newY, int newSize) {
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
        size = newSize;
        color = Color.argb((int) (Math.random() * 256),
                (int) (Math.random() * 256),
                (int) (Math.random() * 256),
                (int) (Math.random() * 256));
        xspeed = (int) (Math.random() * MAX_SPEED * 2 - MAX_SPEED);
        yspeed = (int) (Math.random() * MAX_SPEED * 2 - MAX_SPEED);
        if (xspeed == 0 && yspeed == 0) {
            xspeed = 1;
            yspeed = 1;
        }
    }

   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use BubbleView excatly the same way you work with ImageView in your xml file 
add something like this :

```
<BubbleView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon"
    android:id="@+id/bubble_view"
    />
```

Comment: But what I do with activity_main.xml and its helloWorld message...? And in what xml file must I do what you propose?

Comment: you add this in activity_main.xml